why semaphore empty == 0 but not blocking?
classic producer-consumer problem in C.
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int buf = 0;
sem_t *mutex, *full, *empty;

void *producer(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(empty); // Wait for an empty slot
        sem_wait(mutex); // Acquire mutex for critical section
        buf++;
        printf("Item produced. Count: %d\n", buf);
        sem_post(mutex); // Release mutex
        sem_post(full); // Signal that an item is available
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(full); // Wait for an item to be available
        sem_wait(mutex); // Acquire mutex for critical section
        buf--;
        printf("Item consumed. Count: %d\n", buf);
        sem_post(mutex); // Release mutex
        sem_post(empty); // Signal that an empty slot is available
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t producer_thread, consumer_thread;

    // Initialize semaphores
    mutex = sem_open("/mutex", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
    full = sem_open("/full", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    empty = sem_open("/empty", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 10);

    // Create producer and consumer threads
    pthread_create(&producer_thread, NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&consumer_thread, NULL, consumer, NULL);

    // Join threads (never reached in this example due to infinite loop in threads)
    pthread_join(producer_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumer_thread, NULL);

    // Close and unlink semaphores (optional, but good practice)
    sem_close(mutex);
    sem_close(full);
    sem_close(empty);
    sem_unlink("/mutex");
    sem_unlink("/full");
    sem_unlink("/empty");

    return 0;
}

and here is some of the output:
Item consumed. Count: 1926
Item consumed. Count: 1925
Item consumed. Count: 1924
Item produced. Count: 1933
Item produced. Count: 1924
Item consumed. Count: 1923
Item consumed. Count: 1924
Item consumed. Count: 1923
Item consumed. Count: 1922
Item consumed. Count: 1921
Item consumed. Count: 1920

i made the empty sem to be 10, so expacting it to be a buf limit.
But why the output exceeds the limit?
did everything according to the textbook.
on macbook air m1, so sem_init wont work, use sem_open instead

You are not testing the return values of any of your semaphore operations.  If any of them were failing then that is how you would normally recognize it.


Can't replicate. 2. You came to us to ask for errors; why didn't you do the same thing of the OS? Check your calls for errors! 3. Why are you suing sem_open instead of sem_init? Subsequent runs of your program crash as a result (because sem_open fails, because the semaphore is already open and you don't check for errors).


Side note: your program should be given a way to shut down cleanly.  If you have to kill it to stop it then it will leave the semaphores behind, then fail to open them (because of O_CREAT | O_EXCL) the next time unless you clean those out separately.

Or at minimum, unlink each semaphore as soon as you open it, since you don't need (or want!) to share them between processes.  That will not prevent the program from using them, but it will avoid leaving them behind unless the program happens to be killed between opening one and unlinking it.

thanks bro, the problem was the sem unlink. The first try of my code did not close or unlink the semaphores, so they remain in my os. and all the subsequant tries keep using existing sems. that why the buf out of range. Solved the problem by running a saprate program which unlinking these sems.

I'm glad to have helped.  But I note that as I already observed, opening the semaphores with O_CREAT | O_EXCL means that if they already exist then opening them will fail -- which your program makes no attempt to detect.  Thus, you are not using the existing semaphores.  Where semaphores already exist with the given names, your program does not use semaphores at all.  All of those semaphore operations fail, and the program pays no attention.

The main issue with the script seems to be that its semaphore operations are failing, but the program is not paying attention to recognize that.  The sem_open, sew_wait, and sem_post functions, among others, all convey success / failure information via their return values, as indeed a great many C functions do.  That information needs to be monitored and appropriately acted upon to avoid program misbehavior.
And that's not something to add later.  You should do it when you first write the code because

that's when you're thinking about the required behavior, and are best prepared to decide the appropriate handling of various errors

that's when your code is most likely to have bugs that proper error handling could help you recognize and diagnose

in practice, you're probably not going to come back later to put in all the appropriate error handling.


In this case, lack of proper error handling for your sem_open() calls is a bug because such failures are pretty likely in your case, and when they happen, your program does not get the semaphore behavior it requires.  Lack of proper error handling for your sem_wait() and sem_post() calls contributes to the issue manifesting as mysterious misbehavior instead of as an informative diagnostic.
With that said, a contributing issue is your program failing, inevitably, to manage its semaphores properly.  When you use named semaphores, you must

take effective measures to ensure that they are used only by the processes that are intended to use them.
Opening with the O_CREAT and O_EXCL flags prevents two processes from both using the same semaphore, which helps, but it creates the possibility of locking out other processes from using semaphores with the same names.  This cut both ways for your particular program.

manage their visibility and lifetime appropriately.
This amounts largely to sem_unlink()ing them at the most appropriate time -- which is as soon as possible after you can be sure that all processes that will want to open a particular semaphore have done so.  Like unlinking a regular file, unlinking a semaphore does not destroy it.  That only dissociates it from the namespace so that it cannot be opened by any more processes.  Those that already have it open, or that obtain access by means other than sem_open(), can continue to use it until the close it, whether explicitly or by terminating.  The system will automatically clean up sems that have been unlinked when no process has them open any longer.


Writing error-handling code for lots of function calls can get tedious, and updating lots of error handling code can be downright painful.  As a result, it seems pretty common for people to use macros to help with generating all that error handling.  That has the added benefit of preventing the primary behavior of the program from being obscured behind large amounts of boilerplate error handling.  There are lots of ways to work the details, of which this is one:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <errno.h>

int buf = 0;
sem_t *mutex, *full, *empty;

#define warn_if(val, cond, context) do { \
    if ((val) cond) { \
        perror("warning: " context); \
    } \
} while (0)

#define exit_if(val, cond, context) do { \
    if ((val) cond) { \
        perror(context); \
        exit(1); \
    } \
} while (0)

#define do_or_die(func, paren_args) { \
    exit_if((func) paren_args, == -1, #func); \
}

#define pt_do_or_die(func, paren_args) { \
    exit_if(errno = (func) paren_args, != 0, #func); \
}

sem_t *create_semaphore(const char *name, unsigned int initial_val) {
    sem_t *sem = sem_open(name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, initial_val);
    
    exit_if(sem, == SEM_FAILED, "sem_open");
    warn_if (sem_unlink(name), == -1, "sem_unlink");

    return sem;
}

void *producer(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        do_or_die(sem_wait, (empty)); // Wait for an empty slot
        do_or_die(sem_wait, (mutex)); // Acquire mutex for critical section
        buf++;
        printf("Item produced. Count: %d\n", buf);
        do_or_die(sem_post, (mutex)); // Release mutex
        do_or_die(sem_post, (full)); // Signal that an item is available
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        do_or_die(sem_wait, (full)); // Wait for an item to be available
        do_or_die(sem_wait, (mutex)); // Acquire mutex for critical section
        buf--;
        printf("Item consumed. Count: %d\n", buf);
        do_or_die(sem_post, (mutex)); // Release mutex
        do_or_die(sem_post, (empty)); // Signal that an empty slot is available
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t producer_thread;
    pthread_t consumer_thread;

    // Initialize semaphores
    mutex = create_semaphore("/mutex", 1);
    full = create_semaphore("/full", 0);
    empty = create_semaphore("/empty", 10);

    // Create producer and consumer threads
    pt_do_or_die(pthread_create, (&producer_thread, NULL, producer, NULL));
    pt_do_or_die(pthread_create, (&consumer_thread, NULL, consumer, NULL));

    // Join threads (never returns in this example due to infinite loop in threads)
    pt_do_or_die(pthread_join, (producer_thread, NULL));
    pt_do_or_die(pthread_join, (consumer_thread, NULL));

    // Close semaphores (optional, but good practice)
    warn_if(sem_close(mutex), == -1, "sem_close");
    warn_if(sem_close(full), == -1, "sem_close");
    warn_if(sem_close(empty), == -1, "sem_close");

    return 0;
}

